# How can the function numpy.r_ include[ ]?

Tags: python, function, numpy

I thought a `function` in `python` have to use `()` **signs** to take parameters.

But it seems that `numpy.r_` does not follow this rule. **How come is this possible?**

Comment: See its code in https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/lib/index_tricks.py

Answer (score 2):

`numpy.r_` is not a function but an object of `RClass`. Python allows you to define custom behavior for operators by overloading relevant methods in class. For example, you may define behavior of `[]` operator for your class objects by overloading `__getitem__` method.

```
class Squares:
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return index ** 2
    
squares = Squares()

print(squares[1]) # 1
print(squares[2]) # 4
print(squares[3]) # 9
```

See this tutorial for details : https://realpython.com/operator-function-overloading/